# jQuery autocomplete: disable submit when no results

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, count, submit

I want to disable my submit when jQuery autocomplete finds no results. I'ts working half now, i count my results fine.

The only problem is when i have a result, and i submit, the result springs back to 0, so i can't submit. I want to remember the autocomplete count value when submitting.

i count my results:

```
$('#stock_input').autocomplete({

        source:'autocomplete.php',
        autoFocus: true,
        minLength:1,
    open: function(event,ui){
            count = $(this).autocomplete("widget").find( "li" ).length;
            $('#count').text(count);
    },
    close: function(event,ui){
            count = 0;
            $('#count').text(count);
    }
});
```

Allowsubmit setting:

```
    var allowSubmit = true;
        $("#updatestock_form").submit(function(e){
            if(count === 0){ allowSubmit = false; alert(count); } 
            else { allowSubmit = true; alert(count); }
            if (!allowSubmit) return false;

        //rest of submit code
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code :

```
close: function(event,ui){
            count = 0;
            $('#count').text(count);
    }
```

`this will make count = 0` every time you close autocomplete

and when you submit form the count var will always be 0 which makes `allowSubmit = false`

```
 $("#updatestock_form").submit(function(e){
            if(count === 0){ allowSubmit = false; alert(count); } 
            else { allowSubmit = true; alert(count); }
            if (!allowSubmit) return false;

        //rest of submit code
        });
```

You can check this on submit itself

```
$("#updatestock_form").submit(function(e){
            var count = $('#stock_input').autocomplete("widget").find( "li" ).length;
            if(count === 0){ allowSubmit = false; alert(count); } 
            else { allowSubmit = true; alert(count); }
            if (!allowSubmit) return false;

        //rest of submit code
        });
```

Comment: Thanks, it's a good idea to check on the submit itself. But when i remove the close tag, the count never gets 0, it stays on the last count

Comment: Their is no need to remove `close`, you may need this for some other functionality

Comment: Mmm.. but i never count 0 results. If i type "BBB" and i get 3 (correct) reults, en then i type "BBBB", wich should give me for example 0 results, the counter stays on 3 results. This only happens when there are 0 results. How can i correctly set the counter to 0 when there are no results?

Answer (score 0):

I did it with the following code:

```
$('#stock_input').autocomplete({
        source:'autocomplete.php',
        autoFocus: true,
        minLength:1,
        response: function(event, ui) {
            if (ui.content.length === 0) {
                count_result = 0; //no results
            } else {
                count_result = 1;
            }
        }
});
```

And:

```
$("#updatestock_form").submit(function(e){
    if(count_result === 0){ allowSubmit = false; }
        else { allowSubmit = true; }
        if (!allowSubmit) return false;
});
```